# Horizontal lines in bar plots without first line

Tags: pgfplots

I'm starting to learn pgf-plot and this is my first plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0, ymax=70,
    width=9.5cm,
    symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e},
    xtick=data,
    bar width=15pt,
    axis lines*=left,
    ytick={0,10,...,70},
    xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex},
    ymajorgrids, 
    ]
    \addplot[fill=gray!40] coordinates {
        (a,54)
        (b,60)
        (c,62)
        (d,58)
        (e,51)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to draw horizontal lines from every yticks to the other end of the plot. I tried with `xbar interval` but it didn't work. How should I do it?

**Edit:** nevermind, found it. It was the `xmajorgrids` option. Now what I can't do is to remove the first line from the horizontal grid (first from above, the hline at y=70). Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should probably self-answer this question and ask a separate one.

Comment: the original question was a duplicate of another one, I think in this way it is no more a duplicate and can be answered by someone (hopefully)

Comment: So you want to remove the horizontal grid line at `y=10`?

Comment: @Jake, no, sorry for not being clear, I mean the one at y=70.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one possibility:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0, ymax=70,
    width=9.5cm,
    symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e},
    xtick=data,
    bar width=15pt,
    axis lines*=left,
    ytick={0,10,...,60},                  %changed code
    xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex},
    ymajorgrids,
    extra y ticks=70,                     %new code
    extra y tick style={grid=none}        %new code
    ]
    \addplot[fill=gray!40] coordinates {
        (a,54)
        (b,60)
        (c,62)
        (d,58)
        (e,51)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I did was to remove the value you didn't want from your `ytick` option and then add an extra tick with the removed value but with a no grid style.

Comment: WOuld it also be possible to remove any line with this method? Say, y=40?

Comment: yes, in the worst case scenario just set the full list of ticks `ytick={0,10,20,30,50,60,70},` taking out the one you don't want to be in the grid and readding it as an extra tick.