# pgfplots - Create multiple plots from one table (rows 0--3, 4--7,...)

Tags: pgfplots, foreach

Using JMH in java I have created file. Suppose .csv file looks like this (but far bigger):

```
"Benchmark","Mode","Threads","Samples","Score","Score Error (99.9%)","Unit","Param: capacity","Param: objects"
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaArrayLists.testArrayList","thrpt",1,50,13840788.290265,340713.080893,"ops/s",0,1
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaArrayLists.testArrayList","thrpt",1,50,308084.862046,3363.564803,"ops/s",0,100
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaArrayLists.testArrayList","thrpt",1,50,32961.868917,400.213686,"ops/s",0,1000
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaArrayLists.testArrayList","thrpt",1,50,3326.423048,29.662297,"ops/s",0,10000
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaArrayLists.testArrayList","thrpt",1,50,14480091.281797,201352.449027,"ops/s",500,1
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaArrayLists.testArrayList","thrpt",1,50,316558.184911,3352.761618,"ops/s",500,100
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaArrayLists.testArrayList","thrpt",1,50,33562.619512,290.498672,"ops/s",500,1000
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaArrayLists.testArrayList","thrpt",1,50,3319.397084,22.321262,"ops/s",500,10000
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaArrayLists.testArrayList","thrpt",1,50,14501880.364073,116230.130746,"ops/s",10000,1
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaArrayLists.testArrayList","thrpt",1,50,319336.611259,2659.178072,"ops/s",10000,100
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaArrayLists.testArrayList","thrpt",1,50,33588.319651,243.878605,"ops/s",10000,1000
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaArrayLists.testArrayList","thrpt",1,50,3322.992416,25.905451,"ops/s",10000,10000
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaLinkedLists.testLinkedList","thrpt",1,50,19993525.187572,240143.948149,"ops/s",0,1
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaLinkedLists.testLinkedList","thrpt",1,50,311584.596234,6280.931754,"ops/s",0,100
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaLinkedLists.testLinkedList","thrpt",1,50,30846.002383,749.757479,"ops/s",0,1000
"com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaLinkedLists.testLinkedList","thrpt",1,50,2942.108526,84.974577,"ops/s",0,10000
```

Is it possible to create plot for each *n* rows (eg. 0-3, 4-7, ..) in this table?

I'm beginner with pgf and quite so with LaTeX as well.. I did create some plots without cycle, but it would be most useful to have "automatic graph maker" that I would point in the .csv file and would be given graph.

I have combined [How to draw a graph from CSV with TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245131/how-to-draw-a-graph-from-csv-with-tex) , [How to plot the first n rows of a table using pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199376/how-to-plot-the-first-n-rows-of-a-table-using-pgfplots) and [axis lable in millions/thousands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160928/axis-lable-in-millions-thousands) but I cannot make

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5, width = 12cm, height = 5cm, select coords between index/.style 2 args={
    x filter/.code={
        \ifnum\coordindex<#1\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
        \ifnum\coordindex>#2\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi
    }
}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[/pgfplots/error bars/.cd, x dir = normal, y dir = normal, x explicit, y explicit,title=Lists collections performance,
                    xlabel = Objects,
  legend style={legend columns=-1},
  legend to name={thelegend},
  name={theaxis},
                    ylabel = Add operations ops/s,      
                    y tick label style={ytick scale label code/.code={}, scaled y ticks=base 10:-6, yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick} million},},
                x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, scaled x ticks = false, set decimal separator={,}, fixed},
                    xmin = 1, xmax = 10000,
            ]{lists-results.csv}
        \addplot+[red, mark = o, ultra thick,] [select coords between index={0}{3}]
        table [col sep=comma, ignore chars=\%, x="Param: objects", y="Score",]{lists-results.csv};
        \addplot+[blue, mark = o, thick] [select coords between index={4}{7}]
        table [col sep=comma, ignore chars=\%, x="Param: objects", y="Score",]{lists-results.csv};
        \addplot+[green, mark = o] [select coords between index={8}{11}]
        table [col sep=comma, ignore chars=\%, x="Param: objects", y="Score",]{lists-results.csv};
        \addplot+[purple, mark = o] [select coords between index={12}{15}]
        table [col sep=comma, ignore chars=\%, x="Param: objects", y="Score",]{lists-results.csv};
        \legend{Guava ArrayList(0), Guava ArrayList(500), Guava ArrayList(10000), Guava LinkedList}
        \end{axis}
\node [below] at (theaxis.below south) {\ref{thelegend}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have tried something like this, but it doesn't seem to be working

```
\foreach \n in {0,4...,28}{
    \addplot+[red, mark = o] [select coords between index={\n}{\n+3}]
      table [col sep=comma, ignore chars=\%, x="Param: objects", y="Score",]
       {lists-results.csv};
}
```

<sub><sup>**Additional (marginal) questions would be:**</sup></sub>

<sub><sup>1) Is it possible to shorten the names of Benchmarks?

*like "com.group.name.lists.impl.GuavaLinkedLists.testLinkedList" -> "GuavaLinkedLists"*</sup></sub>

<sub><sup>2) Is it possible to add to the name number from other column?

*like Benchmarks:"GuavaLinkedLists" and Param: capacity":0 ->"GuavaLinkedLists(0)"*</sup></sub>

<sub><sup>3) Is it possible to multiply two columns to create x axis numbers?

*like "Score":3326.423048 and "Param: objects":10000 -> 33264230.48*

[Is it possible to multiply the x coordinates of a plot by a certain factor using pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75531/is-it-possible-to-multiply-the-x-coordinates-of-a-plot-by-a-certain-factor-using)</sup></sub>

<sub><sup>4) How to distribute each column value equally?

[Horizontal space between xticks in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275730/horizontal-space-between-xticks-in-pgfplots)</sup></sub>

<sub><sup>5) How to create horizontal lining?

[Horizontal lines in bar plots without first line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149023/horizontal-lines-in-bar-plots-without-first-line)</sup></sub>

<sub><sup>6) How to export pdf in console?

[How to create pdf with command line using MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21405/how-to-create-pdf-with-command-line-using-miktex)</sup></sub>

Comment: Welcome! There's a key called something like skip rows between, might get you started. (You'll probably get an answer soon, but if not ping me back and I'll take a more detailed look)

Comment: table/skip first= and sample= might do it.  If there had been a MWE I would have tested it.

Comment: @cmhughes I added more details in my question, please look at it

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. The main problem, why your `\foreach` solution isn't working is, because the `\n+3` isn't evaluated. You can test this by, e.g. replacing `select coords between index={12}{15}` with `select coords between index={12}{12+3}` in your "manual" solution, which will raise an error.

I think I also have addressed all your "additional (marginal) questions" except for the last two. Regarding 5) I don't like grid lines, but you already have found the solution so I think you can apply that yourself if you really want/need them. And Regarding 6) I am not sure if you really just meant to output a PDF of "the whole document" or maybe just create a PDF of the plot (alone).

For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xstring}        % <-- needed for string manipulation
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use at least this `compat' level to improve placing of axis labels
        compat=1.3,
        % (almost the) opposite of `skip coords between index'
        % only use x values when the `\coordindex' lays between the two
        % arguments (including), else "skip" them by setting the value to "NaN"
        select coords between index/.style 2 args={
            x filter/.code={
                \pgfmathifthenelse{or(\coordindex<#1,\coordindex>#2)}{NaN}{x}
                \pgfmathresult
            },
        },
        table/col sep=comma,
        table/ignore chars=\%,
    }
    % define a command to create the legend entries
    % (give the row number to the argument)
    \newcommand{\CustomLegend}[1]{
        % store the "Benchmark" entry of the given row number in `\Benchmark'
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{"Benchmark"}\of{\table}
            \edef\Benchmark{\pgfplotsretval}
        % store the "Capacity" entry of the given row number in `\Capacity'
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{"Param: capacity"}\of{\table}
            \edef\Capacity{\pgfplotsretval}
        % create the legend entry
        \addlegendentryexpanded{
            % only use the part of `\Benchmark' between the given two strings
            \noexpand\StrBetween{\Benchmark}{impl.}{s.test}
            % append the capacity entry in brackets if the "Benchmark" entry
            % ends with the given string (else return an empty string)
            \noexpand\IfEndWith{\Benchmark}{ArrayList"}{%
                (\Capacity)
            }{}
        }
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            % read the table from the file
            \pgfplotstableread{lists-results.csv}{\table}
        \begin{axis}[
            title=Lists collections performance,
            xlabel=Objects,
            % changed y axis label and corresponding style
            ylabel=Add operations in million ops/s,
            % use an index for the data points and get the labels from the table
            xtick={0,...,10},
            xticklabels from table={\table}{"Param: objects"},
            y tick label style={
                ytick scale label code/.code={},
                scaled y ticks=base 10:-6,
            },
            % changed positioning of the legend
            legend pos=outer north east,
            % use left alignment for labels in legend
            legend cell align=left,
        ]
            \foreach \n in {0,4,...,12}{
                \addplot+[mark=o,select coords between index={\n}{\n+3}] table [
                % to avoid a numerical issue I have added "+0.1" to x
                % (otherwise for \n=16 the modulus would return 4, because
                % 16 would be something like 15.999)
                    x expr={int(mod(\coordindex + 0.1,4))},
                    y expr=\thisrow{"Score"}*\thisrow{"Param: objects"},
                ] {\table};
                    \CustomLegend{\n}
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]